# Enterprise Architect Add-In ConstLayOutStyles usage

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

Basicly i'm trying to layout a `Diagram` in `Enterprise Architect` with newly added `DiagramObjects` via `Add-In`.

I found that i should use the `LayoutDiagramEx` method.

Next step is usage. Here's some code i'm trying to make work:

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface().LayoutDiagramEx(diagram.DiagramGUID, EA.ConstLayoutStyles.lsCycleRemoveDFS, 4, 20, 20, false);
```

Visual Studio hints that there is an error:

**Interop type 'EA.ConstLayoutStyles' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.**

I cannot find the problem here sadly.

Does anyone know how to use the **ConstLayoutStyles**?

Thanks for the tips or the answer in advance!

Tamas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Instead Try the values directly from below.

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface().LayoutDiagramEx(treeSelectedObject.DiagramGUID, 0x40000000, 4, 20, 20, false);
```

In most cases only the default layout will be assigned.

where LayoutStyle is one of the Enum values from below

[image]

You can find the constant values in EA.
**Scripts -> Local Scripts -> EAConstants-JScript\EAConstants-VBScript**

HTH

Arshad

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this problem because of the setting on the reference to EA.Interop.dll.

If you have the option **Embed Interop Types** as true you would see these kind of errors.

Setting it to false will probably solve the error without losing the ability to use the enumerations defined in the API.